# How to use \page[quadruple] while having a cover as last page in ConTeXt?

Tags: pdf, context-mkiv, lastpage

I am creating a personalised magazine in ConTeXt-LuaTeX. It has a cover (that what you can see before opening the magazine), existing of two .pdf files. It contains several chapters adaptive text, meaning each person gets part of the information. Upfront I cannot calculate the number of pages. I want the magazine to be printed double sided on A4.

**Question**: How can I include additional empty pages, while keeping both cover pages as first and last page? 
In other words, the magazine starts with a cover page, followed by content, zero or more empty pages, another cover page and the total number of pages can be divided by four.

As cover page I use:

```
\startTEXpage
\externalfigure[kaft1][width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]
\stopTEXpage
```

As settings:

```
\setuppapersize[A4] 
\setuplayout[location=double, marking=on]
\setupmargindata[margintext][location=outer]
```

I have read: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition and http://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2008/031897.html  However, I cannot get any of the quadruple examples working. Below part of the error message:

```
tex error       
> error on line 18 in file C:/Users/Acer/Documents/LaTeX/Hebbedingen/cover quadruple cover simple.tex: ! Undefined control sequence

<argument> \??pagebreakmethod \v!nextquadruple 

\setvalue #1->\expandafter \def \csname #1
                                      \endcsname 
\installpagebreakhandler ...\??pagebreakmethod #1}
                                              {#2}
l.18    \fi}


 8       {\ifdoublesided
 9          \!!counta\realpageno
10          \!!countb\realpageno
11          \advance\!!counta 4
12          \divide\!!counta 4
13          \multiply\!!counta 4
14          \advance\!!countb 1
15          \advance\!!counta-\!!countb
16          \executepagebreakhandler\v!yes
17          \dorecurse\!!counta{\executepagebreakhandler\v!empty}%
18 >>     \fi}
19     
20     \protect
...
```

What do you suggest I do?

Comment: **Possible solution:** 
Two parts of LuaTeX code are included. Function: added upto 3 pages so the total number of pages can be diveded  by 4.

`\def\fillthesignature#1{
\directlua{dofile("imposer.lua") 
optimize_signature(#1)}}`

%% The second part of the LuaTeX code to ensure that the last page is the cover.

`\page[yes] % reset the page
\fillthesignature{\the\realpageno}`

%% The last page, hence the cover. 
\noheaderandfooterlines
\copypages[BACKnl.pdf][n=1]`